# Omni channel "End Chat" button throwing an exception

Tags: service-cloud-console, chat, omnichannel, pre-chat, embedded-services

I am using salesforce embedded service chat and when a community user chats with an agent and when the agent clicks on the "End chat" button from Service console app, it is throwing this exception.

[image]

[image]

But Community user is able to end the chat

Any idea?

Comment: Does it happen for all the agents? And across all the browsers?

Comment: yeah its happening for all agents and tested in both chrome and Egde chromium and IE